# Which is more suitable: hash table or BST in terms of serialization, concurrency?

Tags: serialization, concurrency, hashmap, binary-search-tree

I think a Hash Table would be more suitable if we're doing collision resolution via chaining, because for any read or write operation we'd have to acquire lock on that entry (index & value) in hash table whereas we'd have to acquire lock on entire BST to make any updates to it.

I think we need to take lock on entire BST structure, because imagine we've to insert a new node in to the tree, we first have to traverse to reach the right parent position (say node A) and if we haven't acquired lock the tree structure might change and we'd have to start afresh.

In case of hash tables the input would always hash to the same position and we'd know which index to take lock on, which is unknown in case of BST.

Please correct me wherever I'm wrong and help me find the right answer.

P.S: This is an Amazon Interview Question.

Comment: Have you read the [research paper for an efficient concurrent BST by Bronson et al.](http://ppl.stanford.edu/papers/ppopp207-bronson.pdf)?

Comment: I'll read that paper. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think in terms of concurrency what you have said is correct, and a hash table will be a better choice but in terms of serialization I think a BST will be better. This is because in BST we will have only data nodes, however in hash table we will have both key and value pairs for data, as well have few keys for which there will be no value. Thus it will require more space when serialized as compared to BST.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a hybrid solution. Do a hash table where each slot is a binary tree. So say 1024 slots, each with a binary tree. Collisions on the hash go into a binary tree, don't need to lock everything on insert, just the tree you need to update.

Further if you use atomic operations and some cleverness you can make it even more concurrent by avoiding locking altogether. Atomic update to insert the new node, if atomic update fails another thread added a node, simply loop again until you succeed.

**I have already done this** https://github.com/exodist/GSD/tree/master/Structures

This is a highly concurrent hash/tree hybrid. It uses atomic operations, no mutexes. It can spin on insert, but never blocks for reads or updates to existing keys. It can be resized/balanced/etc. You can traverse all entries, etc. Manages its own memory and has callbacks for ref-counting keys/values. You can also 'link' keys in one dictionary to another so that updating a key in the first alters the value of the second.

This design actually has performance increases when you throw more threads at the problem:

(T) is how many threads, ignore MI, slots is how many hash slots are used, and Ops is how many items are being inserted (divide it by threads to see how much each thread does)

```
./performance.run
   T, MI,   Slots,      Ops:      Insert   Rebalance      Update      Resize      Lookup      Immute            
   4, 16,    1024,  5000000:  2.765500363  0.915232065  2.540659476  2.172654813  2.545409560  2.089993698
13.029449975
   4, 16,   32768,  5000000:  2.122459866  1.403548309  2.413483374  1.885083901  2.092272466  2.643681518
12.560529434
   4, 16, 1048576,  5000000:  1.700994809  1.063704010  2.030809367  2.457275707  1.453413924  3.671012425
12.377210242
  16, 16,    1024,  5000000:  0.785675781  2.311281904  1.805610753  0.621521146  0.549546473  0.744009412
6.817645469
  16, 16,   32768,  5000000:  0.497359638  0.316017553  1.257663142  0.610761414  0.390849355  0.825944608
3.898595710
  16, 16, 1048576,  5000000:  0.328308989  0.647632801  1.267230625  1.139402693  0.342399827  1.189220470
4.914195405
  64, 16,    1024,  5000000:  0.129407132  0.767262021  2.631929019  0.157977313  0.103848004  0.177964574
3.968388063
  64, 16,   32768,  5000000:  0.087656606  0.068330231  1.365794852  0.166261966  0.079112728  0.203542885
1.970699268
  64, 16, 1048576,  5000000:  0.074605680  0.284322979  1.372998607  0.650503349  0.084956938  0.828653807
3.296041360
```

Notes: Single run on an i7 with 8gb ram. Uses gcc atomic builtins, in the process of switching from old __sync to __atomic, which may help performance due to memory models.